# tcpdf wordpress error in PHP even tho i followed the tcpdf example 1by1

Tags: php, wordpress, tcpdf

I created a plugin where when you press send, the data in the form should be translated to pdf and saved in a folder for backup purposes.

I'm using the tcpdf api, downloaded the library and put it in my plugin folder. as i try to test it with the givin textexample from the tcpdf site, it just throws up thses errors:

> "Warning: "continue" targeting switch is equivalent to "break". Did
>   you mean to use "continue 2"? in
>   /www/htdocs/w00e68de/msp.rfid-dresden.de/wp-content/plugins/wp-markenbuero/tcpdf/tcpdf.php
>   on line 17778
>
> Warning: fopen(): remote host file access not supported,
>   file://example_002.pdf in
>   /www/htdocs/w00e68de/msp.rfid-dresden.de/wp-content/plugins/wp-markenbuero/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php
>   on line 1854
>
> Warning: fopen(file://example_002.pdf): failed to open stream: no
>   suitable wrapper could be found in
>   /www/htdocs/w00e68de/msp.rfid-dresden.de/wp-content/plugins/wp-markenbuero/tcpdf/include/tcpdf_static.php
>   on line 1854 TCPDF ERROR: Unable to create output file:
>   example_002.pdf"

```
// Include the main TCPDF library (search for installation path).
require_once('tcpdf/tcpdf.php');

// create new PDF document
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);

// set document information
$pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
$pdf->SetAuthor('Nicola Asuni');
$pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example 002');
$pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
$pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');
// remove default header/footer
$pdf->setPrintHeader(false);
$pdf->setPrintFooter(false);
// set default monospaced font
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
// set margins
$pdf->SetMargins(PDF_MARGIN_LEFT, PDF_MARGIN_TOP, PDF_MARGIN_RIGHT);
// set auto page breaks
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);
// set image scale factor
$pdf->setImageScale(PDF_IMAGE_SCALE_RATIO);
// set some language-dependent strings (optional)
if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
// ---------------------------------------------------------
// set font
$pdf->SetFont('times', 'BI', 20);
// add a page
$pdf->AddPage();
// set some text to print
$txt = <<<EOD
TCPDF Example 002
Default page header and footer are disabled using setPrintHeader() and setPrintFooter() methods.
EOD;
// print a block of text using Write()
$pdf->Write(0, $txt, '', 0, 'C', true, 0, false, false, 0);
// ---------------------------------------------------------
//Close and output PDF document
$pdf->Output('example_002.pdf', 'F');
}
?>
```

Comment: 1. Make sure you have enabled `fopen` to open URL's; 2. It's warnings, not errors. You can turn off error reporting and it will be suppressed. 3. It's possible that plugin is not safe and actually throws warning in file tcpdf.php on line 17778

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's two parts to this, so I'll split my answer between the two:

**File Protocol Warning / Failure to Generate PDF:**

You cannot use relative file paths when calling `Output` in `F` mode to save to a local file. You must provide a full file path. Here are some examples:

```
//Generates output file in the same folder as current script.
$pdf->Output(dirname(__FILE__).'/example_002.pdf', 'F');
```

or

```
//Save to the document root.
$pdf->Output($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/example_002.pdf', 'F');
```

**Continue Targeting Switch Warning:**

This warning is a [PHP 7.3 incompatibility warning](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration73.incompatible.php#migration73.incompatible.core.continue-targeting-switch) with whichever version of the TCPDF library you are using. The master branch from the [github repo](https://github.com/tecnickcom/TCPDF) doesn't appear to throw this warning, so try using that version of the library.